WPF - passing a Key/Value from a DataGrid to a custom control
I try to provide to RefactorListItemControl the Key/Value of a dictionary stored in RefactorOperations which is displayed in a 1 column DataGrid
In the parent class, the RefactorOperations property is initialized as regular directory like this
RefactorOperations = new Dictionary<string, List<RefactorOperation>>();
... // adding data to it

I use a DataGrid to display a list of RefactorOperations
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RefactorOperations}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>

     <DataGridTemplateColumn>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <custom:RefactorListItemControl Data="{Binding Value}"></custom:RefactorListItemControl>
             </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn>

 </DataGrid.Columns>

The RefactorListItemControl  class itself looks like this
public class RefactorListData
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public List<RefactorOperation> Operations { get; set; }
}

public partial class RefactorListItemControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(RefactorListData), typeof(RefactorListItemControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDataPropertyChanged));

    public RefactorListData Data
    {
        get { return (RefactorListData)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
    ...

I expect the Key/Value of each RefactorOperations items in the DataGrid to be passed to RefactorListItemControl in the Data Property
Thanks for helping me on this one
[edit]
Apparently the Datacontext of RefactorListItemControl is the KeyValue itself, but I want the Data property to hold that KeyValue pair

Your description of the problem is a little bit confusing. "I expect the Key/Value of each RefactorOperations items[...]" - The items of RefactoirOpertaions are the key-value pairs. Also sending each item to the RefactorListItemControl basically means you should bind it directly to the RefactorOperations dictionary. "[...] in the DataGrid to be passed to RefactorListItemControl in the Data Property" - The property type is obviously incompatible. Please try to improve your summary of your problem and what  you are trying to achieve.

There is nothing in the DataTemplate that can actually "display" something. If you "template" a column, you need at least a TextBlock or something. And your (dictionary) data represent a "parent-child" view (of "keys" and "lists"); and not a simple column of data.

I finaly found how to do it
the current row item is passed with Binding .
<!-- RefactorOperations is Dictionary<string, List<RefactorOperation>> -->
<DataGrid x:Name="modificationsDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding RefactorOperations}">
  <DataGrid.Columns>

      <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto">
          <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <!-- current row DataContext is List<RefactorOperation> -->
                  <custom:RefactorListItemControl KeyValue="{Binding .}"></custom:RefactorListItemControl>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>

  </DataGrid.Columns>

